# Very large electric field intensity confusion

Tags: electrostatics, electric-fields

We know that electric field intensity:
E=(1/4πe)*(q/r^2)
For 1 coulomb charge at 1 metre distance the value of electric field intensity will be equal to 9*10^9 N/C.Isn't the value for Newton too large,what am I missing?Sorry if the question is wrong.

Comment: Yes,electric force is very strong force,Its not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Seems a bit vague to me just plugging some random numbers into a formula. You should think of a physical system or experiment and use realistic values for the parameters of that experiment/system. Also you might prefer to calculate a more familiar quantity like force instead of electric field.